# Haskell ways to filter out a list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and its functions are a little confusing. The goal is to take a list comprehensions and obtain digits that is a palindrome and starts with the digit 3. I have successfully obtain a list comprehensions of palindrome, but got lost to how to also filter out the digit that does not start with 3.
I have something like this right now, what would be a better approach or way to think about this.

```
isPalindromeThatStartsWithDigit3 a = [ a | a<-[1..a], show a == reverse(show a) && filter ...]
```

Comment: You don't need to say `filter` in a list comprehension -- a Boolean condition already means filler in that context

Answer (score 3):

As @luqui noted in the comments, Boolean conditions or [guards](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.11) are effectively filters in the context of list comprehensions. In the following code, I assume you wanted to enumerate all palindromes up to some value having some integral prefix.

```
isPalindrome :: (Show a) => a -> Bool
isPalindrome n = show n == reverse (show n)

startsWith :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
startsWith []       _        = True
startsWith _        []       = False
startsWith (x : xs) (y : ys) = x == y && startsWith xs ys

palindromesStartingWith :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> a -> [a]
palindromesStartingWith x y = [ z | z <- [1..y],
                                    isPalindrome z,
                                    startsWith (show x) (show z) ]
```

For example:

```
*Main> palindromesStartingWith 1 1000
[1,11,101,111,121,131,141,151,161,171,181,191]
*Main> palindromesStartingWith 34 10000
[343,3443]
```

The documentation linked above describes list comprehensions and gives an explicit translation between list comprehensions and the list monad.